# Плагин live server для Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

В чем смысл плагина если при автоматическом обновлении страницы, страница возвращается к началу экрана, и мне приходится каждый раз его вниз прокручивать...

Comment: А он вам че должен позицию скролла запоминать? Этот плагин нужен для автоматического обновления файлов в браузере при их изменении

Comment: Городить целый плагин что бы заменить кнопку обновить в браузере? Ну не знаю...

Comment: Ну, справедливости ради, если Вас устраивает кнопка "обновить" - Вы можете просто задизейблить плагин. Или удалить его. Как я видел - его обычно используют в сочтании с автосохранением и с двумя мониторами: просто пишешь код на одном мониторе, и он мгновенно отображается на другом в том виде, как его будет показывать браузер.

Comment: Так и работаю. При маленьком куске кода это действительно удобно. но при длинной странице мне приходится все равно взаимодействовать с браузером на втором мониторе вручную.

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите.

Этот плагин запускает простой http - сервер на Вашем компе, на порту 5500.

Почему это бывает нужно?

Потому, что не все сайты, которые Вы будете верстать, состоят только из статиченских файлов.

Обычно всё выглядит так: до тех пор, пока на странице есть только html, css и клиентский js - Вам вполне достаточно кнопки "обновить".

Но как только Вам надо что то делать с http - сервером - вот здесь  понадобится плагин.

Причем, это не единственный вариант: многие сценарии разработки предлагают своё решение. Например, если Вы пишете на node.js - то, скорее всего, сама нода будет запущена у вас в качестве http сервера.

Я тут чуть чуть погуглил, и, кажется, [нашел](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/231), как сделать так, чтобы при перезагрузке страницы позиция не терялась: всё своодится к установке галочки в параметре LiveServer > Settings > Full Reload:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я видел - плагин обычно используют в сочтании с автосохранением и с двумя мониторами: просто пишешь код на одном мониторе, и он мгновенно отображается на другом в том виде, как его будет показывать браузер.

Comment: Понял.
Просто смущает то что по умолчанию браузер запоминает позицию если обновлять через кнопку обновить, а через плагин нет. Как я понял это не решить через настройки плагина?

Comment: Нашел обсуждение: https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/231 все сводится к установке параметра Full Reload, сейчас добавлю в ответ!

Comment: Да, я тоже нашел. Спасибо вам.